# unable to know how to remove spaces in output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orderedlist>
   <listitem>
      <para>
         <citation>
            <citetitle pubwork="other">aaaaaa</citetitle>
            ccccccccccc
         </citation>
         .
      </para>
   </listitem>
   <listitem>
      <para>
         <citation>
            <citetitle pubwork="other">cccc</citetitle>
            mmmm
         </citation>
         .
      </para>
   </listitem>
</orderedlist>
```

When I'm running my XSLT on this there are some spaces(or can be line breaks), like the ones between `</span>` and `.`.

Is there a way of removing these spaces? I used `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, but I didn't find it much helpful.

Below is my XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="orderedlist">
        <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="orderitempara" match="listitem/para">
            <li class="item">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:if test="./@num">
                    <xsl:variable name="phrase">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('P',./@num)"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="newphrase" select="translate($phrase,'.','-')"/>
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$newphrase">
              </xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
                        <span class="phrase">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="para" match="para">
    <div class="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="citation">
        <span class="font-style-italic">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="citetitle">
        <span class="font-style-italic">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Here is a working demo. http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxz

**Current o/p:**

```
 <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
      <listitem>
         <li class="item">
            <div class="para"> <span class="font-style-italic"><span class="font-style-italic">aaaaaa</span>
                  ccccccccccc
                  </span>
               .

            </div>
         </li>
      </listitem>
      <listitem>
         <li class="item">
            <div class="para"> <span class="font-style-italic"><span class="font-style-italic">cccc</span>
                  mmmm
                  </span>
               .

            </div>
         </li>
      </listitem>
   </ol>
```

**Expected o/p:**

```
 <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
      <listitem>
         <li class="item">
            <div class="para"> <span class="font-style-italic"><span class="font-style-italic">aaaaaa</span> ccccccccccc</span>.               
            </div>
         </li>
      </listitem>
      <listitem>
         <li class="item">
            <div class="para"> <span class="font-style-italic"><span class="font-style-italic">cccc</span> mmmm</span>.               
            </div>
         </li>
      </listitem>
   </ol>
```

Please let me know how Can I get the required o/p.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you change the template for the text nodes to

```
 <xsl:template match="text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
        </xsl:template>
```

then the output is as desired I think. http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxz/1

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, this looks good, but observing closely, the space `</span> ccc`, is not preserved, which has to be. :(

Comment: Then you need to be more precise about your requirements. Looking at your expected output, it contains about half the whitespace characters that follow the "." in the input, but not all of them. Getting rid of unwanted whitespace becomes easy if you can specify precisely which whitespace is unwanted, but if you can't, then it's a rather hard problem.